# Can not receive Message from application running under another account

Tags: wndproc

I'm trying to communicate between applications running under different user accounts.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

http://imageshack.com/scaled/large/692/p3vc.png

However, this isn't working using SendMessage.  Why is this?  What can I do to fix this situation?

Comment: when it doesn't work call GetLastError. If result is 5 (Access denied) your message is blocked by User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI). So it means SendMessage is OK but pb is access rights.

Comment: Yes GetLastError return 0x5 - Access denied. Both apps are running under accounts which have admins rights. What to do now ?

Comment: Never used it but look at ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx to let some message go through UIPI

Comment: ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx does not help :-(  I will use NamedPipes like workaround

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1674398/1111557